# How do I make my app use less storage?

Tags: android, launcher, android-launcher

I am making a launcher. Currently it takes up about 20 mb. What can I use to drop it to at most 9 mb?

Comment: 20 MB is nice! Seriously...

Comment: Are you sure? I don't want it to eat up space. I'm trying to make it connect to a server where it can store the info there, and have the info backed up in case the user disconnects. Issue I'm having is publishing the server too. How can I publish my server (I use Ubuntu).

Comment: I am not sure what you are asking, but 20 MB is definitely ok... I've seen apps taking about 250 MB (hello, Facebook).

Comment: Lol that is true Facebook eats up storage like me in a buffet.

Comment: What do you think of the name? Its called Samus (after the metroid character as she is the most popular female leads in games)

Answer (score 0):

Compress all your images with pngquant. It will reduce the size significantly atleast 30% i think.

Comment: I literally have no photos but I'll see if compressing the icon will do much

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to profile your apk?
I recommend you to figure out the problem by profiling apk.
Android Studio (2.2 Preview 1)  has nice APK Analyzer.
http://android-developers.blogspot.jp/2016/05/android-studio-22-preview-new-ui.html

If the problem is classes.dex size, let's try Proguard to reduce the java classes.
https://developer.android.com/studio/build/shrink-code.html